# Dúvida VBA - Erro em tempo de execução '91'

Tags: vba

```
'Procedimento para o Comando Entrar
Sub Entrar()

 'converte texto usuario para minusculo - formando um padrao
    frmLogin.txtUsuario = LCase(frmLogin.txtUsuario)

' Primeira parte - Verifica os campos vazios
If frmLogin.txtUsuario = "" Then
    MsgBox "Entre com o nome do Usuário", vbInformation, "USUÁRIO"
    Exit Sub
End If

If frmLogin.txtSenha = "" Then
    MsgBox "Entre com a senha do Usuário", vcInformation, "SENHA"
    Exit Sub
End If

' Segunda parte - verifica se é administrador e se for entra na planilha
If frmLogin.txtUsuario = "admin" And frmLogin.txtSenha = "admin" Then
    MsgBox "Bem Vindo Administrador.", vbOKOnly, "ACESSO LIBERADO"
    gravarRelatório
    LimparfrmLogin
    Unload frmLogin
    Application.Visible = True
    Sheets("USUÁRIO").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Sheets("REL_ACESSO").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Sheets("CONDIÇÃO.H.EXTRA").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Sheets("UTIL.CONTROL.PONTO").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Sheets("EMPREGADO.TESTE1").Select

    Exit Sub
End If

' Terceira parte - verifica se o usuário e senha estão no banco de dados
linha = 2
Usuario = frmLogin.txtUsuario
Senha = frmLogin.txtSenha

Do Until Sheets("USUÁRIO").Cells(linha, 1) = ""
If Sheets("USUÁRIO").Cells(linha, 1) = Usuario And Sheets("USUÁRIO").Cells(linha, 2) = Senha Then
    MsgBox "Bem Vindo " & Usuario, vbOKOnly, "ACESSO LIBERADO"
    gravarRelatório
    LimparfrmLogin
    Unload frmLogin
    Application.Visible = True
    Sheets("USUÁRIO").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    Sheets("REL_ACESSO").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    Sheets("CONDIÇÃO.H.EXTRA").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    Sheets("UTIL.CONTROL.PONTO").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    Sheets("EMPREGADO.TESTE1").Select
    Exit Sub
End If
linha = linha + 1
Loop

    MsgBox "Usuário ou Senha Inválidos", vbCritical, "ACESSO NEGADO"
    LimparfrmLogin
    frmLogin.txtUsuario.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Não se preciso informar outro código ainda. Quem puder ajudar e precisar de mais informações.

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Qual a dúvida? Onde ocorre o problema? Além de postar o código, é importante você explicar como o problema ocorre.

Comment: Ricardo, bem vindo ao Soft. Acesse a Ajuda e faça o Tour, para usar melhor os recursos daqui,e ver como tratar as perguntas e respostas. Procure ser claro em suas questões.

Comment: Olá. Bem vindo ao SOPt. O que os colegas querem dizer é que não basta só colocar o código, porque desse jeito alguém interessado em te ajudar precisa copiá-lo para colocar numa planilha e tentar testar. Ou então analisar cuidadosamente linha a linha pra tentar achar onde está o erro. Como *você já sabe onde está o erro*, por favor clique em [edit] e adicione essa informação (a linha onde ocorre) na pergunta. E, não esqueça: faça o [tour] e leia principalmente [ask].

Comment: Oi Ricardo, e ai? A resposta te serviu ou foi útil? Aqui na comunidade marcamos (check abaixo das setas ao lado da resposta) a resposta quando isso ocorre, e podemos votar acionando as setas das respostas e de perguntas também. Aguardo um retorno teu, pois se não resolveu o problema nos dê mais informações para ajudá-lo. Faça o tour se não fez ainda, é importante!

Answer (score 0):

O erro **91** do **VBA** é:

> **Variável Objeto ou variável de bloco With não atribuída**

Este tipo de erro não indica onde o problema ocorreu, assim, ele deve estar na rotina **LimparfrmLogin**. Dependendo do que está nesta rotina o problema irá ocorrer.

Para verificar isso, crie pontos de interrupção e acompanhe com as teclas **F8** (passo a passo) ou **F5** (até encontrar outro ponto de interrupção).

Comment: Não acho que isso seja necessariamente o problema, por que ele faz unload do form mas imediatamente termina a sub com `exit sub`. Logo, o loop não continua.

Comment: Ok, vou editar, pois o problema deve estar nesta rotina e esse tipo de erro não aponta onde ele ocorreu.

Comment: Quem deveria apontar onde ele ocorreu é o AP, na pergunta (afinal, o Excel para na linha onde o erro ocorreu). :) Até ele fazer isso, você vai ter que ficar tentando chutar onde o erro potencialmente está ocorrendo. Talvez vc acerte, mas potencialmente pode gastar o seu tempo de bobeira.

Comment: Ok, entendi. Teve outra questão assim que indiquei o uso dos pontos de interrupção e o problema foi encontrado, acho que é o caso aqui.

Comment: Leo, a sua resposta efetivamente *não responde* à pergunta, porque você diz que talvez esteja na outra rotina que o AP não postou o código. De fato, não sabemos ainda onde está o erro. Por isso eu insisto que faltam informações e deveríamos esperar. Pra vc não correr o risco de levar negativações, eu sugeriria comentar ao invés de responder. Ou seja, remova esta resposta e responda novamente (de forma mais concreta e acertiva) depois que o AP atualizar a pergunta. :)

Comment: OK, como a pergunta está "aberta", acredito que o que indiquei seja a "solução" (como serviu para outro, acho que é o mesmo caso, não atentou para os pontos de interrupção), já que ele pede "ajuda" e não é específico na pergunta. Não há como ser preciso sem o restante do código. Vou aguardar..por enquanto..